# Вопрос с подменой переменной на константу

Tags: python, api

Есть переменная `price` которая тянется из api(биржи)
Предположим, что она равняется 3000. `price = client.get_margin_price_account()`
Я хочу выставить автоматический ордер на продажу, когда достигнет `3300`
Я не могу написать `new_price = 300 + price`, поскольку сам `price` постоянно меняется и будет подтягиваться, так как обновляется из `client.get_margin_price_account()`
Как сохранить переменную в константу, чтобы в дальнейшем ее использовать?

Comment: посчитайте new_price при создании ордера и больше не меняйте ее...

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит. Нужно проводить сделку типа Fill or Kill. Она подразумевает выставление ордера по факту наступления события.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно у вас недопонимание, что означает запись:

```
new_price = 300 + price
```

Когда выполняется эта строка программы, то в переменную `new_price` записывается *текущее* значение выражения справа от знака присваивания. Дальнейшие изменения переменной `price` **никак не влияют на значение переменной `new_price`**.

Т.е. это не формула, которая задает соотношение между величинами, и автоматическим пересчетом (как происходит в excel-e). Для того чтобы переменная изменилась, нужно чтобы исполнилась стока программы с присвоением переменной нового значения.

Так что для вашей задачи, нужно в какой-то момент времени (в какой именно, это только вы знаете), задать значение `new_price` и после этого переменную `new_price` не изменять. А при изменении `price` проверять достигло ли ее значение того, которое хранится в `new_price` и делать что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, было недопонимание работы python

Comment: А если данное выражение находиться в цикле?

Comment: Каждый раз когда выполняется оператор присваивания, значение меняется. Если присваивание в цикле - значит меняется каждый раз, когда поток выполнения доход до оператора присваивания.